# ehcache Get the running time of timeToIdleSeconds

Tags: java, ehcache

Is there a way to get the current running value of ehcache's timeToIdleSeconds? Let me clarify my question. For example you set the timeToIdleSeconds to 60 seconds. Assuming 40 seconds have passed, is it possible to get the value of the remaining time which is 20 secs? I am trying to use this value in my Java code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, to my knowledge, no way of doing this as of Ehcache 2.8.x.

Also, this does not seem the role of a Cache anyway.